# Coronavirus CARES Act - How Do I Apply For A Small Business Loan As A One Person S-Corporation?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, s-corporation, covid-19

The US Chamber of Commerce recently published a [quick guide](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/4228131/US%20chamber%20of%20commerce%20PPP%20loan%5B1%5D.pdf?utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=85472235&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-9Nzfxk81VqjjVuoG18S-X_GUi0r5gnDUiV3wvwsfnpYTSnrJzWbKJpMdefSKSO5z3jt8j9kmOcAzPpiy713FwlG3Ettg&_hsmi=85472235) on how businesses can file for a loan backed by the government under the CARES stimulus act.

The guide splits up businesses as either an employer or a self-employed person.  I am a one person S-Corp, which one of the two groups would I fall under?  Are there any published guidelines that specifically pertains to one person S-Corps?

Comment: Do you have employees (payroll), or are you just wanting this for your expenses?